# How to compare and edit two csv files in java depending on one column?

Tags: java

```
public class CompareCSV {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String path = "C:\\csv\\";
        String file1 = "file1.csv";
        String file2 = "file2.csv";
        String file3 = "file3.csv";
        ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> al2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        BufferedReader CSVFile1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/C:/Users/bida0916/Desktop/macro.csv"));
        String dataRow1 = CSVFile1.readLine();
        while (dataRow1 != null) {
            String[] dataArray1 = dataRow1.split(",");
            for (String item1 : dataArray1) {
                al1.add(item1);
            }
            dataRow1 = CSVFile1.readLine();
        }
        CSVFile1.close();

        BufferedReader CSVFile2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/bida0916/Desktop/Deprecated.csv"));
        String dataRow2 = CSVFile2.readLine();
        while (dataRow2 != null) {
            String[] dataArray2 = dataRow2.split(",");
            for (String item2 : dataArray2) {
                al2.add(item2);
            }
            dataRow2 = CSVFile2.readLine();
        }
        CSVFile2.close();

        for (String bs : al2) {
            al1.remove(bs);
        }

        int size = al1.size();
        System.out.println(size);

        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:/Users/bida0916/Desktop/NewMacro.csv");
            while (size != 0) {
                size--;
                writer.append("" + al1.get(size));
                writer.append('\n');
            }
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to compare two csv files in java and want to have the complete details removed of one csv file from the other by comparing the first column of both the files. Currently I am getting a csv file with one column only having all details jumbled up.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding all values of all columns to a single list, that's why you get the mess in your output:

```
ArrayList<String> al1=new ArrayList<String>();
//...
String[] dataArray1 = dataRow1.split(",");
for (String item1:dataArray1)
{ 
    al1.add(item1);
}
```

Add the complete string array from your file to your list, then you can access your data in a structured way:

```
List<String[]> al1 = new ArrayList<>();
//...
String[] dataArray1 = dataRow1.split(",");
al1.add(dataArray1);
```

But for removal of rows I'd recommend to use `Map`s for faster access, where the key is the element on which you decide which row to delete and the value is the full row from your cvs file:

```
Map<String, String> al1 = new HashMap<>(); // or LinkedHashMap if row order is relevant
//...
String[] dataArray1 = dataRow1.split(",");
al1.put(dataArray1[0], dataRow1);
```

But be aware, that if two rows in a file contain the same value in the first column, only one will be preserved. If that's possible you might need to adopt that solution to store the data in a `Map<String, Set<String>>` or `Map<String, List<String>>`.

At this point I'd like to recommend to extract the file-reading to a separate method, which you can reuse to read both of your input-files and reduce duplicate code:

```
Map<String, String> al1 = readInputCsvFile(file1);
Map<String, String> al2 = readInputCsvFile(file2);
```

For the deletion of the lines which shall be removed, iterate over the key set of one of the maps and remove the entry from the other:

```
for (String key : al2.keySet()) {
    al1.remove(key);
}
```

And for writing your output file, just write the row read from the original file as stored in the 'value' of your map.

```
for (String dataRow : al1.values()) {
    writer.append(dataRow);
    writer.append('\n');
}
```

**EDIT**

If you need to perform operations based on other data columns you should rather store the 'split-array' in the map instead of the full-line string read from the file. Then you have all data columns separately available:

```
Map<String, String[]> al2 = new HashMap<>(); 
//...
String[] dataArray2 = dataRow2.split(",");
al2.put(dataArray2[0], dataArray2);
```

You might then, e.g. add a condition for deleting:

```
for (Entry<String, String[]> entry : al2.entrySet()) {
    String[] data = entry.getValue();
    if ("delete".equals(data[17])) {
        al1.remove(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

For writing your output file you have to rebuild the csv-format.
I'd recommend to use [Apache commons-lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) `StringUtils` for that task:

```
for (String[] data : al1.values()) {
    writer.append(StringUtils.join(data, ","));
    writer.append('\n');
}
```

Comment: Markus thanks for the input but can you please tell me how to remove a complete row based on a element because right now one column is getting deleted and i want complete row deleted

Comment: @Biswajit I'm not sure if I understood your question properly, but I updated my answer regarding accessing other columns of the data from the CSV files. // A full row is deleted with `map.remove(key)`. // If my answer is helpful, please accept it by ticking the checkmark.

Comment: thanks @markus you have been a great help but I have been trying way too many ways but still not able to achieve at the desired result. Can you plz advice me how to remove say for e.g. 50 rows contained in a CSV file named A from a csv file named B having 2500 rows. Actually I have one CSV file with 50 rows which should always be compared with new CSV files coming from client and if these rows are there in client csv , they should be removed.

Comment: Sorry, @Biswajit, SO is no coding service. I think I provided you with extensive information on how to solve your task. If you need help on other **specific** problems you're welcome to come back and ask new questions.  // One last hint: start again with a small version of your problem and work yourself step-by-step to the full solution.